Barcode 128 with Polish language
I am developing an ms-access application generating report with barcodes (VBA).  For this, I installed libre barcode font and used this font to generate the bar codes.  The application works perfectly on my machine with English settings and locale.
When I try to install the font on a polish machine. The font gives special characters in the middle of the barcodes (see the image below).  What are the possible workarounds to solve this issue?  Change character encoding on the Polish machine ? Use another font that would be compatible with Polish settings. Which one?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Expected result


According to Wikipedia, Barcode 128 supports 128 Ascii and Latin-1 character set - I would guess that the characters you display are not part of this character set and therefore cannot be part of the barcode.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.  Although even only regular number like 12345... are generating this kind of characters.  I suspect that the issue is that the asci characters used by the encoding used by the Polish setting is not properly recognize by the font.  The question is how can we get around this.

You need to be more specific. What exactly are you encoding in the examples above ? Clearly not just 12345 ? Code128 has 3 different modes (A,B,C) and there may be autoswtiching between them. This switch uses special bytes.  If you want to do it "right" purchase a barcode module like TEC-IT for Office. It will save you much time debugging and works as expected.

Make sure you are displaying the correct text, for instance with the following for i = 1 to len(strBC) , debug.print asc(mid(stsrBC,i,1)) , next i . The only values should be "48-57 for 0-9 and 65-90 for A-Z and 97-122 for a-z".

MyICQ,  you have a point. I added the expected result with standard character.  As you can see nothing matches. I hope this can guide

Having a better look at it.  Only number are displayed correctly.  Letters are not coming up right.
